# I tried validating and I get this mesaage : Method [validateString] does not exist

Tags: php, string, validation, laravel, store

It seems my **validation** isnt quite correct, so Im getting this error message while Im trying to store fees into my database.

I have previosuly checked related questions with but it didnt quite help. I created **FeeValidator** that extends **Validator** with this array:

```
 <?php namespace \Events\Services\Validations;

    use \Events\Services\Validations\AbstractValidator as Validator;

    class FeeValidator extends Validator {
        protected $rules = array(
            'title'         =>      'required',
            'price'         =>      'required|numeric',
            'quantity'      =>      'integer',
            'valid_from'    =>      'date',
            'valid_to'      =>      'date',
            'ticket_limit'  =>      'integer',
            'url_redirect'  =>      'string',
        );
    }
```

Then I have a FeesRepository with this **store() function** in the **FeesRepository** class:

```
<?php namespace \Events\Repositories;

use \Events\Models\Fee as Fees;
use \Events\Models\Event as Event;
use \Events\Repositories\Contracts\FeesRepositoryInterface;
use \Events\Services\Validations\FeeValidator;

class FeeRepository implements FeesRepositoryInterface {

    protected $theme;

    protected $feeValidator;

 public function store($eventId) {

        $validation = $this->feeValidator->with(\Input::all());

        if ($validation->passes()) {
            $fee = new Fees;
            $fee->event_id          = $eventId;
            $fee->title             = \Input::get('title');
            $fee->price             = \Input::get('price');
            $fee->quantity          = \Input::get('quantity') == "" ? 1 : \Input::get('quantity');
            $fee->discount          = \Input::get('discount');
            $fee->valid_from        = \Input::get('valid_from');
            $fee->valid_to          = \Input::get('valid_to');
            $fee->coupon            = \Input::get('coupon') == "" ? null : \Input::get('coupon');
            $fee->tickets_limit     = \Input::get('ticket_limit');
            $fee->url_redirect      = \Input::get('url_redirect');
            $fee->save();

            $id = $fee->event->id;
            if ( $fee->event->eventable_type == '\Events\Models\Training' )
            {
                return \Redirect::route('admin.training.edit' , array($id));
            }
            elseif( $fee->event->eventable_type == '\Events\Models\Meetup' ) {
                return \Redirect::route('admin.meetup.edit' , array($id));
            }
            else
            {
                return \Redirect::route('admin.conference.edit' , array($id));
            }

        }

            else {
                             return \Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->feeValidator->errors());
                 }

    } 

}
```

Finally you can check my **store() function** in the **FeesController**:

```
<?php namespace \Events\Controllers;

use \Events\Repositories\FeeRepository as Fee;
use \Events\Models\Fee as Fees;use \Events\Services\Validations\FeeValidator;


    class FeesController extends \BaseController {

        protected $fee;

        protected $feeValidator;

        public function __construct(Fee $fee , FeeValidator $feeValidator)
        {
            $this->fee = $fee;
            $this->feeValidator = $feeValidator;
        }

     public function store($eventId) {
                  return $this->fee->store($eventId);
           }
      }
```

Im wondering what is the issue. Can someone give me a hint! **Thanks**!

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: post your error in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your validation  you can use default validation which already build in Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation to display errors you can use **JS** or simply in your form **ex :**

```
 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
@if ($errors->has('email'))
  <span class="help-block">
     <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
   </span>@endif
 </div>
 </div>
```

**EDIT :** hey you have simple validation so you have a easy way to use validation like this but your way is correct but why can't you try easy way ?
This for Laravel 4.2 easy way to use validation example

```
Route::post('register', function()
{
    $rules = array(...);

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using Laravel 4.2 and I am trying whats not working and it doesnt work. Tried this two suggestions. Maybe the array **$rules** isnt defined properly.

Comment: @ajax_27 chek mayb it will help you

Comment: I tried validating like you suggested me and it does work, but my project is built in another way so I am trying to follow that convention. The issue was the Laravel 4.2 validation rule. Thanks again for help!